# casting pointers in C++

Tags: c++, casting

I have a serial port returning uint8 in the following way

```
uint8 bucket[255];
res = COM.com_read((char *)&bucket);
```

how can i pass **bucket** pointer into **buff** pointer in the function given below:

```
ssize_t send(int s, const void *buf, size_t len, int flags);
```

Answer (score 4):

`&` is not required in `com_read`, and you should write this:

```
//after removing '&'
//bucket being an array converts to pointer automatically
res = COM.com_read((char *)bucket);  //Dont use &
```

Or, even a better cast would be `static_cast`:

```
res = COM.com_read(static_cast<char*>(bucket)); //C++ Style cast!
```

And while sending `bucket` to `send`, you don't need to cast. It is done implictly by the compiler, because the target type is `void*`, and any pointer can implicitly convert to `void*`.

Comment: for some wierd reason i cast as (const char *) and it works however i cast static_cast<char*>(bucket) and it did not work.

Comment: @user945511: Post the signature of `com_read`. Also, what do you mean by "it didn't work"? Did it give compilation error, or what?

Comment: this is the signature: int RS_232::com_read(char * xchg_space). it gave error "can`t cast uint8 to char*", but this error is shown not in `com_read` function but in "send(int s, const void *buf, size_t len, int flags)"

Answer (score 2):

There is no casting required, it is done implicitly (any pointer can be casted to a `const void*` implicitly).

Note that when explicitly casting, you should prefer C++-casting operators:

```
res = COM.com_read(static_cast<char *>(bucket));
```

Answer (score 1):

Static_cast will do the trick to and from void*, but are you sure you need an explicit cast? I think this should be done implicitly for you

```
static_cast<void *>(bucket)
```

Comment: i have the following error both ways (cast and no cast) Multiple markers at this line
 - initializing argument 1 of 'size_t strlen(const 
  char*)'
 - invalid conversion from 'uint8*' to 'const char*'